# Deserializing public key with python's cryptography module

Tags: python, serialization, cryptography, deserialization, public-key-encryption

I am writing a python script that involves sending a public key over a network. I am using <https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/.>

```
public_key = self.node.public_key
pem = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

deserialized_key = load_pem_public_key(pem)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: load_pem_public_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend'
```

I am therefore unable to deserialize the key - I am confused because according to the documentation, load_pem_public_key() takes 1 required argument (data) and 1 optional argument (backend).

Comment: You should be sending the entire certificate, not just the public key.

Comment: cryptography < 3.1 requires backend arguments. You can get a default backend with `from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend` and pass `default_backend()` (note that you must invoke it as a method!) as the argument. You can also upgrade to 3.1+.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like you use `cryptography==3.0` or lower where `backend` argument is required https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/3.0/src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py#L19

Bump to `cryptography==3.1` or put something to `backend` arg

Answer (score 0):

Even with `cryptography==3.1` I still had the problem.

I can't provide the `backend` arg either because it was triggered in a library (`python-jose==3.1`). Upgrading to `python-jose==3.2` (=current latest) didn't help either.

Installing `python-jose-cryptodome==1.3.2` did help.

---

Relevant section of the `python-jose` documentation:

> Th[e naive python] backend is always installed but any other backend will take precedence if one is installed.